# How to adjust navigate('/login?redirect=something') for new version of react router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

```
const checkoutHandler = () => {
    history.push('/login?redirect=shipping')
}
```

First post here. As far as I understand this should go to login if we are not logged in else it goes shipping. How can we adjust so that it works with new react router.

I used navigate like this:

```
navigate('/login?redirect=shipping')
```

It goes to http://localhost:3000/login/shipping. I was expecting this to go http://localhost:3000/shipping.

No console errors just No routes matched location "/login/shipping"

Comment: Should work :-)

Comment: What do you mean by "didn't work", did you get an error message or did nothing happen?

Comment: The `navigate` function ***is*** the replacement of the `history.push` function. Logically that function unconditionally navigates to `"/login"` regardless of any authentication status. What isn't working? Are there any errors in the console? Please provide better details.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Sorry for confusion. I updated that part.

Comment: Sorry, what makes you think `navigate('/login?redirect=shipping')` would navigate to `"/shipping"` instead of `"/login"`? Is there something more to your code you're not letting on to? I'm starting to think that the code *does* navigate to `"/login"` and a user *logs in* or whatever and you are trying to redirect the user to `"/shipping"` afterwards. Please share a more complete [mcve] with more details regarding the issue and what you are trying to accomplish overall.

Answer (score 0):

I was also stuck exactly in the same problem. What I did is I just changed my logic & it's working fine for me. If the user is logged in navigate to the shipping page else navigate to the login page.

```
  const checkOutHandler = () => {
    if (isAuthenticated) {
      navigate("/shipping");
    } else {
      navigate("/login");
    }
  };
```